# I have a problem creating a bsc token sniper bot

Tags: python, tkinter, python-requests, cryptocurrency, web3py

I am trying to make a token snipe bot that works in the binance smart chain,i also want it to have a little tkinter app in which you can set certain functions

```
import tkinter as tk
import requests
import web3
import time

API_ENDPOINT = "https://bsc-api.binance.org"
CONTRACT_ADDRESS = "0x1234567890abcdef"

def get_current_price():
    url = f"{API_ENDPOINT}/v1/ticker/price?symbol={CONTRACT_ADDRESS}"
    response = requests.get(url)
    price = float(response.json()["price"])
    return price

def snipe_token(threshold):
    # Connect to the Binance Smart Chain
    w3 = web3.Web3(web3.HTTPProvider("https://bsc-dataseed.binance.org:443"))

    # Get the current price of the token
    price = get_current_price()

    # If the price is below the threshold, make the purchase
    if price < threshold:
        # Unlock the account
        w3.eth.defaultAccount = "acc adress"
        w3.personal.unlockAccount(w3.eth.defaultAccount, "password")

        # Load the contract and make the purchase
        contract = w3.eth.contract(address=CONTRACT_ADDRESS, abi=abi)
        tx_hash = contract.functions.buy().transact()

        # Wait for the transaction to be mined
        tx_receipt = w3.eth.waitForTransactionReceipt(tx_hash)

        # Print the transaction details
        print(f"Successfully purchased token for {price} BNB")
        print(f"Transaction hash: {tx_hash}")
    else:
        print(f"Price is above threshold ({threshold} BNB)")

def sell_token(price):
    # Connect to the Binance Smart Chain
    w3 = web3.Web3(web3.HTTPProvider("https://bsc-dataseed.binance.org:443"))

    # Unlock the account
    w3.eth.defaultAccount = "0x1234567890abcdef"
    w3.personal.unlockAccount(w3.eth.defaultAccount, "password123")

    # Load the contract and make the sale
    contract = w3.eth.contract(address=CONTRACT_ADDRESS, abi=abi)
    tx_hash = contract.functions.sell(price).transact()

    # Wait for the transaction to be mined
    tx_receipt = w3.eth.waitForTransactionReceipt(tx_hash)

    # Print the transaction details
    print(f"Successfully sold token for {price} BNB")
    print(f"Transaction hash: {tx_hash}")

def check_price():
    # Get the current price of the token
    price = get_current_price()

    # Print the current price
    print(f"Current price: {price} BNB")
    return price

# Create the main window
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Token Sniper")

# Create the threshold entry field
threshold_label = tk.Label(root, text="Snipe threshold (BNB):")
threshold_entry = tk.Entry(root)

# Create the start button
def start_clicked():
    # Get the snipe threshold from the entry field
    threshold = float(threshold_entry.get())

    # Run the snipe loop
    while True:
        # Check the current price of the token
        price = check_price()

        # Set the sell threshold (in BNB)
        sell_threshold = 0.02

        # If the price is above the sell threshold, sell the token
        if price > sell_threshold:
            sell_token(price)
        else:
            snipe_token(threshold)

        # Wait one minute before checking again
        time.sleep(1)
start_button = tk.Button(root, text="Start", command=start_clicked)

# Arrange the widgets in the window
threshold_label.grid(row=0, column=0)
threshold_entry.grid(row=0, column=1)
start_button.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2)

# Run the main loop
root.mainloop()
```

it even says that i that i havent installed web3 library which is not the case,
i cannot seam to find a library that can do what i want my program to do other than web3
and as it seams web3 doesnt want to comply

Answer (score 0):

At first glance, I see that you have incorrectly configured the connection to the BSC. The HTTPProvider method is located in the Web3 class of the web3 library.

```
import web3


# Set the HTTP provider endpoint for the BSC
bsc_provider = web3.Web3.HTTPProvider("https://bsc-dataseed.binance.org/")

# Create a web3 object using the BSC provider
w3 = web3.Web3(bsc_provider)

# Check the connection
print(w3.is_connected())
```